# JPanel to a JFrame

Tags: frame

Program 1: The Frame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CourseGUI extends JFrame {


public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame(""); 
frame.setSize(800, 600); 


frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true); 

}


}
```

Program 2: The Panel

public class TopPanel extends JPanel {

```
public static void main(String[]args)  
{  

 JPanel panel=new JPanel();  


 JFrame frame=new JFrame("Create a JPanel");  


 frame.add(panel);  


 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  


 frame.setSize(800,600);  

   JLabel Crse = new JLabel("Course Info");
Crse.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));

 frame.setVisible(true);  



}  
}
```

How can I set the Panel to make it a inside of the frame. Also It has to be at the top location, and I don't even know if the code for the Panel is correct, I can only test it wit h the CourseGUI.java, from what my teacher tells me. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Oops the frame is not suppose to have a main in their..

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CourseGUI extends JFrame {
    public CourseGUI()
    {
        // invokes super (JFrame) constructor with the title "CourseGUI Frame"
        super("CourseGUI Frame");

        // make a new panel, set its background color and dimensions
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBackground(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(800,600);
        // set the size of the JPanel to the defined dimension
        topPanel.setPreferredSize(d);

        // set the layout of CourseGUI (which is a JFrame, since it extends from JFrame)
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // add the panel to the north
        this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // make sure that pressing "X" closes the JFrame
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(800,600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new CourseGUI();
    }

}
```

The idea here is that you're extending CourseGUI from JFrame, so it **is a** JFrame. Therefore, you can call methods like `this.setSize(800,600)`. Then you make a new JPanel and add it to the JFrame.

Make sure that you create your JLabel inside the constructor somewhere, perhaps after the JPanel.
To add it to the JPanel, first set the layout of the JPanel by calling `topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout())`, then add it using `topPanel.add(Crse, BorderLayout.NORTH)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package test;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TopPanel extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Create a frame");
        // frame.add(panel);// frame can not insert anything by "add" , you need
        // use "getContentPane" before "add"
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        Button button = new Button("111");// test for add button
        JLabel Crse = new JLabel("Course Info");
        Crse.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        panel.add(Crse);
        panel.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```